# Can I list all features that are required by projects in my Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I just finished a simple project and now I'm moving on to something else. Before that, I need to document how to compile and run the project so that when somebody else (or me in six months) needs to work in it, he'll be able to read how to start.

I installed some visual studio features for the project (eg. IIS Express). Is there a way to get a full list of these, or do I just have to look through installed features and try to remember which do belong to the project?

Comment: Main menu -> Tools -> Extensions and Updates, then you choose "Installed". Is this what you were searching for?

Comment: I have also installed things for other projects.

Comment: I don't think that Visual Studio can do this. What I would do is this: Create a new solution with a new project. Add all code from your simple project to it. Try to compile. Now write down every step you have to take in order to make it compile.